# Build Scala Project using mvn command

Tags: java, scala, maven

I am working to build an existing Scala project using Maven.

The instructions required:

```
scala-ide: http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/e38/scala210/stable/site
m2eclipse-scala: http://alchim31.free.fr/m2e-scala/update-site
build-helper-maven-plugin: https://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/forge-sites/m2e-extras/0.15.0/N/0.15.0.201206251206/
```

I don't wanna use Eclips and heavy IDEs, I prefer using line commands.
I installed Scala and Maven .

```
brew install maven
brew install scala
```

How can I build a project using Maven.

I have a repo : scalaproject

I tried :

```
mvn scalaproject
```

But it didn't work out;

Comment: You probably need the Scala plug-in for Maven. See for example http://prystash.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/playing-with-scala-and-maven.html and https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do it like this

```
       mvn archetype:generate \
      -DarchetypeGroupId=org.scala-tools.archetypes \
      -DarchetypeArtifactId=scala-archetype-simple  \
      -DremoteRepositories=http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases \
      -DgroupId=com.company \
      -DartifactId=myMavenScalaProject \
      -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: It is interesting how maven changes our conception of "easily".

Comment: @user3001937 is that answers your question ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use gradle.

http://www.gradle.org/

try something like

```
gradle setupBuild
```

So, edit the build.gradle to

```
apply plugin:  'scala'
```

#### Update

Final version of build.gradle (without any comment) could be:

```
apply plugin:  'scala'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.9.1'
}
```

Put your classes in ./src/main/scala/ 
After that, you can run...

```
gradle build
```